Wirelessly screen casting as extended monitor while maintaining internet connection
Recently the wire in my laptop mainboard to HDMI connector has been corroded due to water, and I need to use a second screen. I have looked at some reviews of some wireless display adapters and here are my requirements:

Internet connection needs to be maintained during casting (I have a standalone wifi adapter with USB connector, if that matters)
The second screen needs to be displayed on its own resolution and in extended mode, not just mirroring the first screen
Optional: sound transmission

I use it for working (note taking, researching, coding, watching lectures and presentations) and I'm not sure how much lagging is acceptable. But I guess I don't really need it to be smooth.
I'm not sure if Miracast is suitable for me. Which products would you recommend?

I would recommend a USB to HDMI dongle. Current casting solutions are not suitable for much more than movies. (where the delay is not important)
